# TOR browser delete history securely

Tags: 12.04, browser, tor

I downloaded the Tor Browser off of: https://www.torproject.org

I am curious if this deletes everything SECURELY from your browsing history automatically when you close it, or is there something else I need for that to be implemented. I want it so if my computer was stolen no one can find out anything I browsed, so it is wiped securely.

Comment: Check out [tails](https://tails.boum.org/).

Answer (score 1):

From [tor browser specification](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#disk-avoidance):

> The User Agent MUST (at user option) prevent all disk records of browser activity. The user should be able to optionally enable URL history and other history features if they so desire.

So if this is correctly implemented, the so-called *private mode* in other browsers is the default here. There is nothing to delete in the first place because normally nothing is kept on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Tor will automatically clear your browsing history, but someone with enough know how could recover that information from your hard drive.

Are you using an SSD or Hard Disk?

If your using a hard disk install Bleachbit.

Download the lastest version here for the version of Ubuntu you are using:

http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux

Open Bleachbit as administrator

Select 'Edit' and then 'preferences'

Check the box that says 'overwrite files to hide contents'

Click 'ok'

Under the 'System' option on the left select 'free space'

Hit 'delete'

This will overwrite all the free space where data was cached for your tor session and make that data virtually unrecoverable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious:
This would delete everything and just the last session or a period of time? What if I want all TOR sessions deleted that I have ever used from before?

Comment: Also, the same steps work for Chrome or no?

Comment: Same Steps work for chrome, select chome options to delete in bleachbit...To be 100% on your tor session overwrite the tor folder you extracted at least 7 times.